# Excel: Dynamically extract rows, from a fixed size table, that don't have missing (#n/a) value in a particular column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I was working on a problem in Excel and got stuck with this issue.

Basically I have a table as such (the one just below) where in I pull values for the 'Percent with Category' column based on the value in 'Branches' column using vlookup.

What I have

[image]

Now what I want is a table (like the one below) that excludes the rows which have a missing or #n/a value in the 'Percent with Category' column and I am not able to get it.

What I want

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Filter and copy?

Comment: with Office 365: `=FILTER(A:C,NOT(ISERROR(C:C)),"")`

Comment: @BigBen I need it to happen dynamically. I am actually using a slicer that updates the 'Percent with Category' column but the resulting vlookup result in missing values (which is normal). Now for my purpose I only want those rows that are non-N/A after this slicer and vlookup.

Comment: The `FILTER` function does not operate over the `used range` only, so something like `NOT(ISERROR(C:C))` has to process more than a million cells, irrespective of how many cells in that range contain data. Microsoft really have to do more to inform the Excel community as to which functions can operate over arbritrarily large ranges with little or no detriment to calculation performance: currently the misunderstanding is widespread.

Comment: @JosWoolley or is it down to the users to improve themselves?

Comment: @VedantSrivastava using Scott's solution, if you combine it with `CTRL` + `T` you can make a table format, and instead of referencing the entire column you can reference only the table portion of it and if rows are added or deleted the formula will adjust accordingly. These keeps your sheet lean for the reason Jos Woolley hinted at, this would address that.

Comment: @SolarMike Not quite sure what you mean. If you mean that you disagree that MS should do more to inform Excel users as to potentially large hindrances to workbook performance then I would respond: 1) I wholeheartedly disagree and 2) The comments section to this question is certainly not the right place to initiate such a debate!

Comment: @JosWoolley but you started said debate. But I still think users should be improving themselves… Some users might need to read the instructions on a pack of toothpicks.